# Puppet not using the specified environment path

Tags: vagrant, puppet, vagrantfile

I am new to vagrant and puppet and having problem getting environment and environment_path to work.

My working directory looks like this:

=> C:/vagrantdemo/Vagrantfile

=> C:/vagrantdemo/environments/testenv/manifests/default.pp

and I specify the environment as follows:

```
config.vm.provision "puppet" do |puppet|    
  puppet.environment = "testenv"
  puppet.environment_path = "../vagrantdemo/environments"        
  puppet.manifests_path = "manifests"
  puppet.manifest_file = "default.pp"
end
```

Someone with tips on how to make the evironment work and not gething the error: **puppet provisioner: The manifests path specified for Puppet does not exist: C:/vagrantdemo/manifests**

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because, from the tag:  GENERAL VAGRANT SUPPORT IS OFF-TOPIC. Support questions may be asked on https://superuser.com.

Answer (score 0):

I change environment_path to environments and took away manifest_path and _file, things worked.